How to make 2 Android emulators connect with WebRTC?
I have developed a peer-to-peer application with WebRTC technology.
I would be interested in making the WebRTC data channel open between 2 emulator instances running under Android Studio.
There is a state in data channel connection which is "connecting", before they open a data channel, and they keep being in this state forever.
They both can reach the server that sends SDPOffer-SDPAnswer from one client to another in order to make them connect directly afterwards.
My best guess is that there is no ICE candidate that they can gather and send over to make an agreement.
I tried to run one emulator in VM, and another one on my host with Android Studio, but the data channel still not opened.
I also tried port forwarding to the host PC, but still not managed to make them connect to each other directly.
A: adb forward -s emulator-5554 tcp:5000 tcp:5000
B: adb forward -s emulator-5556 tcp:5001 tcp:5001
Thank you, and any help is appreciated!

The common answer here is "since your service will need a TURN server anyway, configure it and the Android simulator will just use it".

I am not allowed to use nor TURN- nor STUN-servers. We have to solve this on LAN somehow...

in that case you will need to forward the whole dynamic port range (48k and up) for UDP between the emulators.

Alright, how exactly, should I do that?
I saw a command: emulator @Pixel8_API_34 -ports 49152,65535
